# React: how can i enforce the structure of 2 objects in 2 different files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react project and i am trying to add a file for each environment (development.js and production.js) 
 
both files contain only a single object that has all the data of a certain environment.
Now i need to enforce the same structure for both objects in a way that if i change the object in development.js the compiler will raise an error if i don't change it in production.js as well. 
example: 
development.js = {**server**: localhost} 
production.js = {**serverName**: website.com} 
 *//this shouldn't be allowed since the keys are different*

Usually the internationalization work this way

Comment: That's what TypeScript is for

Comment: btw, if I give you something that can share objects over websockets.. would that help?

Comment: @Wendelin can you please share an example?

Comment: @TheBombSquad thank you but i  am not really sure if sharing objects over websockets can help me here

Comment: you want to make sure an object in one environment is maintained in the other environment right?